# Переопределить env_keep для определённого пользователя в sudoers

Tags: linux, debian, sudo

Я хочу переопределить env_keep для одного определённого пользователя в системе. (Для всех пользователей - работает без проблем).

Почитал man sudo и man sudoers, немного погуглил - но так и не понял, почему не срабатывает [конструкция](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13246/176784)

```
Defaults:www-data env_keep+="SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
```

(был также вариант не `+=` а просто `=`)

Что-то я упускаю, но что?

Вот мой `/etc/sudoers` (я в нём ничего не менял):

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "@include" directives:

@includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

А вот мой `/etc/sudoers.d/www-data`:

```
Defaults:www-data env_keep="SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
```

Проверял стандартно: вошёл по SSH, посмотрел что есть переменная `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, затем меняю sudoers и пробую проверить:

```
sudo -u www-data -s /bin/bash -c 'echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK'
sudo -u yetanotheruser -s /bin/bash -c 'echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK'
```

Ожидаю в первом случае увидеть непустую переменную, во втором - пустую.
Работает как я уже говорил, если я меняю глобальный `Defaults   env_reset` на `Defaults env_keep` (или ставлю `Defaults env_keep+="SSH_AUTH_SOCK"`), хотя по документации должно работать и для отдельных пользователей судя по комментариям на so.

Система под debian11 если это важно для понимания механики. Пользователь именно www-data, т.е. без шелла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Defaults:username` применяется не к тому пользователю, от имени которого выполняется команда, а к пользователю, вызывающему `sudo`

Вам нужно в `sudoers` вместо `www-data` указать `Defaults:your_user env_keep="SSH_AUTH_SOCK"`, где `your_user` - это имя вашего пользователя в системе.

Правда, в этом случае `sudo` в любого пользователя будет сохранять переменную: и `sudo -u www-data -s /bin/bash -c 'echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK'`
и `sudo -u yetanotheruser -s /bin/bash -c 'echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK'` выведет непустое значение.

Comment: А! Вот он, тот слон которого я не заметил читая man! Для моего случая подходит прекрасно: моя потребность логиниться из ansible в www-data, так что это явно галка.